# Peventing access toekn collision

Tags: oauth-2.0, login-with-amazon

I am using LWA to create an application, There are several micro services that can call my auth service. I want to prevent 2 services from having access token collision.

So, assume service A calls auth service with refresh token 'xyz' and gets an access token.
Now, service B invokes auth service with refresh token 'xyz' and gets another access token.

since refresh token lives indefinitely I am finding it hard to securely prevent collision for access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auth service should be keeping track of the tokens issued. In case of corruption, the auth service can invalidate the associated tokens. If you do, then you can do a simple check against this list and retry.

Refresh tokens should roll after getting used, i.e., you should generate a fresh refresh token when one is exchanged for an access token. Refresh tokens should *not* live indefinitely.